# Can I turn this clipping mask object into a regular shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, clipping-mask

I am working in **Illustrator** with this clipart, and part of the hand is a clipping mask I cannot seem to turn into a "normal" shape:

[image]

When I release the **Clipping Mask**, I get:

[image]

This is what the **Layers Panel** looks like, the **Clipping Mask** gives the shape its form and then cuts through a skin-toned square":

[image]

I tried following [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/127152/illustrator-can-i-expand-a-clipping-mask), but it didn't work. None of the **Pathfinder** or **Expand** actions produce the desired result.

The file is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/problem-shape-2).

**How do I turn this element into a "normal" shape?**

Comment: Just copy the shading on square onto the clipping mask shape and delete square.

Comment: I don't know how to do that - can you explicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Index Finger has a clipping mask on it to support a gradient fill (which can't be seen because its behind the card).

It's a simple thing to remove.

- Select All
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Release` from the menu
- Select the (now visible) rectangle fill edge and delete it
- Select the "hollow" shape for the index finger and fill it with the flesh tone.

You *could* stop here, or if you want simple, basic, flat art...

- Select All
- Hit the `Merge` Button on the **Pathfinder Panel**

[image]

(CS6 animation)

Comment: Does the trick! Thanks!